auto mount not working with fatab entry
I am trying to mount /tmp in a separate partition.  fstab looks like this (there are no ticks before the hashtags, I just added them in the post so that it doesn't make the text bold and super large):
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.

#
 
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a

# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices

# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

#

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation

UUID=9bc94035-5d5f-490e-94cd-bd67c4efc158 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation

UUID=9F32-8C7E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=50321a1f-543e-4ca6-94ce-1741709a26e9 /home ext4 nosuid,noexec,nodev,rw 0 2

UUID=c25c831a-cd3b-4cf3-909c-628fa41cf648 /tmp ext4 auto,loop,nosuid,noexec,nodev,rw 0 0

home is successfully mounted but not tmp  executing df shows /tmp mounted on /dev/loop16.  Issuing mount -a does not mount it either,  It will mount if I issue mount /dev/sda7 /tmp in the terminal.  I tried to get around this by creating a startup script in /etc/init.d contining the mount command.  That also didn't work.  I thought maybe automount was a problem so I turned off automount in the dconf-editor. That also didn't work and usb sticks still automount.  I verified the UUID is correct.  I cut and pasted it from disks.  Ubuntu version 22.04.4 LTS

Are you sure you want the loop mount option there? That's likely causing mount to automatically create the /dev/loop16 device. In any case, systemd has its own way of mounting and managing temporary directories which may be conflicting with your attempts.

You nailed it.  Removing the loop option in fstab solved the issue.

Please add some details on how and why this fixed it.
